# Give a chicken armor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way to give a chicken armor in vanilla minecraft? I wanted to make a chicken like LogDotZips Drumstick, but couldn't figure out how to give a chicken a diamond helmet. Is he just teleporting a baby zombie with invisibility and a helmet on to the chicken, or does the chicken actually have a helmet on? If anyone known how to do this, that would be great!

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a link or picture to what you're referencing so that we may answer more accurately.

Comment: I found a link to a video he made where he had the chicken. The video content has nothing to do with the question, the video is just an example of the chicken.[Chicken with Helmet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bf6QOYGb2_E) @Skylinerw

Comment: i have found a link that makes custom mobs, all you have to say is what mob you want and what armor is on him (also swords) this is 1.9:http://www.minecraftupdates.com/summon-command-1.9 i believe there is a 1.8 one but i did not find it

Comment: It was an answer.  It was converted to a comment because it doesn't actually answer the question, therefore cannot be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what specific chicken youre talking about, but you can put armor(with commands) on a chicken. I am fairly certain that the armor will provide damage resistance, but without mods the armor will not render.